# Существует ли правило, по которому используется творительный падеж во фразах типа "уровень владения языкОМ"?

Tags: падежи

Существует ли правило, по которому используется творительный падеж во фразах типа "уровень владения языкОМ"??
Вопрос задал мне иностранец (лингвист), изучающий русский язык.